# How to create an integration test for a Spring Boot controller using MockMvc and Spring Security filters?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, integration-testing, spring-boot-security

I have a Spring Boot application that uses Spring Security to protect routes. Every time a user tries to access an endpoint, it goes through a security filter to authenticate the user. Now, I would like to create an integration test for a controller using MockMvc.

I've followed the official documentation, but I keep getting errors related to a custom bean from the WebSecurityConfig and its related dependencies. I've tried various combinations of annotations such as @SpringBootTest, @WebMvcTest, @ContextConfiguration, and @AutoConfigureMockMvc, but I can't seem to get it working.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
public class CsrfShowcaseTests {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

private MockMvc mvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply(springSecurity()) 1
            .build();
}
```

...

My goal is to have a controller integration test that tests only the controller layer, mocks dependencies, and uses a mock user (@WithMockUser) to pass the authentication filters.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to set up an integration test that meets these requirements?

Comment: You aren't following the documentation, at least not for Spring BOot. If you would you would be using `@SpringBootTest` (for a full integration test) or `@WebMvcTest` for a sliced test. Which is what you apparently want. Ditch all the annotations you have now an add `@WebMvcTest(YourController.class)` and ditch your `setup` method as well and just `@Autowired` on your `MockMvc` field. Now use `@WithMockUser` (or provide credentials in the request) to specify the user.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for the answer. 

Using your approach, it fails to load the application context. Error not being able to create bean with name jwtRequestFilter, which is a custom filter i add before UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.

Comment: Which is something you need to fix, which is probably done by adding some mocks for services it needs.

Answer (score 1):

*spring-security-test* dependency provides good support for mocking users for integration tests..

You can use

```
@WithAnonymousUser or @WithMockUser
```

Apart from this, to run the integration test you can :

- Either use (this will enable complete context and you can mock the service layer using @MockBean):

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
```

- Or use can try using below setup :

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(YourController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@ImportAutoConfiguration(classes = {SecurityConfig.class})
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: When i use the first option it does not behave correctly. When executing a method without a @WIthMockUser, instead of getting 403 on a protected route, i get 200. 

And when using the second option with all of the annotations, the application context can not be loaded and i get an error related to not being able to create bean with name jwtRequestFilter which is a custom filter i created. 

Kind of blocked now.

Comment: You can try adding this custom filer in the list of classes for autoconfiguration .. in place or in addition to SecurityConfig.class as mentioned above

Comment: Also, when you are using @WithMockUser, you can try defining restricted roles etc for the dummy username ..as part of configuration.. and hope that will give you the desired 403...

Comment: Apparently i need to create a custom spring security configuration without the filter.